# How can I filter dataframe based on null/not null using a column name as a variable?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to list a dataframe where a specific column is either null or not null, I have it working using -

```
df[df.Survive.notnull()] # contains no missing values 
df[df.Survive.isnull()]  #---> contains missing values
```

This works perfectly but I want to make my code more dynamic and pass the column "Survive" as a variable but it's not working for me.

I tried:

```
variableToPredict = ['Survive'] 
df[df[variableToPredict].notnull()]
```

I get the error - `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

I'm sure I'm making a silly mistake, what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So idea is always is necessary Series or list or 1d array for mask for filtering.

If want test only one column use scalar:

```
variableToPredict = 'Survive'
df[df[variableToPredict].notnull()]
```

But if add `[]` output is one column `DataFrame`, so is necessaty change function for test by `any` (test if at least one NaN per row, sense in multiple columns) or `all` (test if all NaNs per row, sense in multiple columns) functions:

```
variableToPredict = ['Survive']
df[df[variableToPredict].notnull().any(axis=1)]

variableToPredict = ['Survive', 'another column']
df[df[variableToPredict].notnull().any(axis=1)]
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Survive':[np.nan, 'A', 'B', 'B', np.nan],
                   'another column':[np.nan, np.nan, 'a','b','b']})

print (df)
  Survive another column
0     NaN            NaN
1       A            NaN
2       B              a
3       B              b
4     NaN              b
```

First if test only one column:

```
variableToPredict = 'Survive'
df1 = df[df[variableToPredict].notnull()]
print (df1)
  Survive another column
1       A            NaN
2       B              a
3       B              b

print (type(df[variableToPredict]))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

#Series
print (df[variableToPredict])
0    NaN
1      A
2      B
3      B
4    NaN
Name: Survive, dtype: object

print (df[variableToPredict].isnull())
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
Name: Survive, dtype: bool
```

If use list - here one element list:

```
variableToPredict = ['Survive']
print (type(df[variableToPredict]))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

#one element DataFrame
print (df[variableToPredict])
  Survive
0     NaN
1       A
2       B
3       B
4     NaN
```

If testing per rows it is same output for `any` or `all`:

```
print (df[variableToPredict].notnull().any(axis=1))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool

print (df[variableToPredict].notnull().all(axis=1))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

If test one or more columns in list:

```
variableToPredict = ['Survive', 'another column']

print (type(df[variableToPredict]))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

print (df[variableToPredict])
  Survive another column
0     NaN            NaN
1       A            NaN
2       B              a
3       B              b
4     NaN              b
```

---

```
print (df[variableToPredict].notnull())
   Survive  another column
0    False           False
1     True           False
2     True            True
3     True            True
4    False            True


#at least one NaN per row, at least one True
print (df[variableToPredict].notnull().any(axis=1))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool

#all NaNs per row, all Trues 
print (df[variableToPredict].notnull().all(axis=1))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding `all` at the end

```
df[df[variableToPredict].notnull().all(1)]
```